# Can dbt tests be dependent on one another?

Tags: dbt

I was wondering if we can create tests depending on each other. For example, if the first fails, run the second on and so on and skip downwards tests wherever the tests succeed.

The goal would be to save CPU consumption on superfluous tests if the major one passes.

Any idea on how to achieve something similar? or how to build a test with these criteria?

Comment: can you give a more detailed example? There situation-dependent ways to do this as of now.

Comment: also, what orchestrator are you using to deploy to production? dbt Cloud? Airflow? CRON? GitHub Actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dbt has many ways to select subsets of tasks. the docs give a good selection of [test selection examples](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/test-selection-examples).

My advice would be to group your tests into distinct phases using either `tag`s or [`YAML` selectors](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/yaml-selectors). You might even get away with having your phase one tests be `--schema` and phase two be `--data`.

In your orchestrator (Jenkins, Circle CI, GitHub Actions) you'd add your control flow (`if-then`) logic. Below is a hacky bash script example.

```sh
echo 'phase one: running'
if dbt test --tag phase_one; then
    echo 'phase one: passed'
else
    echo 'phase one: failed'
    echo 'phase two: running,
    if dbt test --tag phase_two; then
        echo 'phase two: passed'
    else
        echo 'phase two: failed'
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Ahhh, so I'd have to do the control flow in the orchestration tool (In my case Jenkins)? Would that be possible to be done in a dbt macro? The idea would be to call dbt test and automatically handle this situation, but in this case, I guess I would have to use dbt run-operation, right?

Comment: I don't have a lot to add, but I'm working in a migration of DW using dbt as the transformation tool and some of these tests would be used just in this scope, which means, once the migration ends, mostly likely the tests would be dropped. Another example could be related with your comment above, on running these tests after a PR is open or whatever git flow.

Comment: I don't think you'd need `run-operation` unless you have a macro, but what exactly would you want wrapped in a macro? conditional calls to`dbt test`?

Comment: p.s. have you seen the [dbt-audit-helper package](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-audit-helper) package? My team is also migrating DWs and it has been so helpful once we set up external tables to the old db.

Comment: The macro would wrap the queries for the data tests and then I'd have the control flow there. I haven't seen this package before, seems pretty useful! Thank you for your comments, those were helpful!